# Excel spreadsheet (2010 of 2013)

Tags: microsoft-excel, named-ranges

I'm hoping someone may be able to help?  I've been asked to edit an excel file used for process requests.  The person that created the file retired last year.  There is a drop down list on sheet 3 of 4 that i need to edit but I've been having trouble finding the source.   I tried data- data validation- data validation.  The source code showing is `=MicroTMs`, but I haven't been able to find where this is actually located, and the current drop down list has about 25 items.

Any suggestions on how to find the `=MicroTMs` so i can edit the drop down list?

Comment: It's a named range. Go to the named range manager (Name Manager in Formulas tab)

Answer (score 1):

Given that MicroTMs is not an excel function, it refers to what is known as a "Custom Range"

A custom range is a collection of cells that has been created with a name attached to it.

In Excel 2010 and Excel 2013, this is accessed through `Defined Names` and you can use the `Name Manager` to view and delete the current defined names. You can find this in the Formulas tab.
[image]